# How to show an image over an edittext in listview as an info window?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a listview with every list item contains two Edittext View.I need to show an image as info window over the EditText when the screen opens for very first time and remove that if user clicks anywhere on the screen.I am not able to understand how do I place that image just above the edittext.For reference I am attaching the screen below:

[image]

Please guide me How can I place that image for the first listitem edittext.

Comment: You can use `seterror` method for this.

Answer (score 0):

you should use custom Dialog for specific position on the screen. whenever user open at very first time Dialog will be show.

```
public static void shiftMessageDialog(Activity context, String message,
            int theme) {
        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.shift_message_dialog);
        RelativeLayout rv = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rv);



        // set the custom dialog components - text

        TextView messageTxt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message_txt);



        messageTxt
                .setText("Remember to close up the store and we have training at 10am");


        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for this purpose.

**Code Snippet**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View popUpView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null, false);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.select_dropdown);
popupWindowProperty = new PopupWindow(popUpView, anchorView.getWidth(),
        300, true);         
popupWindowProperty.setContentView(popUpView);
popupWindowProperty.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
        bitmap));
popupWindowProperty.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popupWindowProperty.setFocusable(true);
popupWindowProperty.showAsDropDown(anchorView, 0, 0);
```